# Работает ли вообще тег <hr> c target?hr:target{}

Tags: html, css

Хочу, чтобы нижнее подчеркивание появлялась только при активной ссылке, но не могу реализовать...
Не получается. Вообще возможно ли это реализовать[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался так:

```
#hrrr:target{
display: block;
width: 100%;
border: none;
background-color: #ffaa00; 
height: 3px;
margin-top: 1px;
margin-left: 50px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Список действующих псевдоклассов можно посмотреть на https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors#Pseudo-classes

для активной ссылки, думаю лучше использовать класс :active
:target применяет стили к объекту на который адресует ваша ссылка

https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#target-pseudo

http://htmlbook.ru/css/target